# Reserved keywords in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reserved-words

What JavaScript keywords (function names, variables, etc) are reserved?

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords

Answer (score 112, accepted):

We should be linking to the actual sources of info, rather than just the top google hit.

http://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Reserved_Words

JScript 8.0:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyab5c8.aspx

Answer (score 1512):

Here is my poem, which includes all of the reserved keywords in JavaScript, and is dedicated to those who remain honest in the moment, and not just try to score:

```
Let this long package float, 
Goto private class if short.
While protected with debugger case,  
Continue volatile interface.
Instanceof super synchronized throw, 
Extends final export throws.  

Try import double enum?  
- False, boolean, abstract function, 
Implements typeof transient break!
Void static, default do,  
Switch int native new. 
Else, delete null public var 
In return for const, true, char
…Finally catch byte.
```

Comment: How about `yield`?

Comment: This poem is a legend! But unfortunately the included words were reserved in ES3 (byte, long, etc.) that are no longer reserved as of ES5, ES6 and next versions.

Comment: Updated with few more Reserved keywords:
                  
"Let this long package float, 
Goto private class if short.
While protected with debugger case,  
Continue volatile interface.
Instanceof super synchronized throw, 
Extends final export throws.  

Try import double enum?  
- False, boolean, abstract function, 
[ yield arguments eval await ] 
Implements typeof transient break!
Void static, default do,  
Switch int native new. 
Else, delete null public var 
In return for const, true, char
…Finally catch byte."

Answer (score 63):

To supplement [benc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60396/), see [Standard ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf). These are the official reserved words, but only a pedant ignores the implementation to respect the standard. For the reserved words of the most popular implementations, that is firefox and internet explorer, see benc's answer.

The reserved words in EMCAScript-262 are the *Keyword*s, *Future Reserved Word*s, *NullLiteral*, and *BooleanLiteral*s, where the *Keywords* are

```
break     do        instanceof  typeof
case      else      new         var
catch     finally   return      void
continue  for       switch      while
debugger  function  this        with
default   if        throw
delete    in        try
```

the *Future Reserved Word*​s are

```
abstract  export      interface  static
boolean   extends     long       super
byte      final       native     synchronized
char      float       package    throws
class     goto        private    transient
const     implements  protected  volatile
double    import      public 
enum      int         short
```

the *NullLiteral* is

```
null
```

and the *BooleanLiteral*s are

```
true
false
```

Comment: Joseph, thanks for adding that info. I found that PDF in google, but didn't have time to open and read it all.

Comment: The "abstract" future reserved word is not mentioned in neither the ES5 spec nor the ES6 draft. Where did that come from?

Comment: Found it! It was present in ES3 as a future reserved word, along with a long list of others, but it was removed in ES5.

Comment: What kind of answer is this. It doesn't even rhyme.

Comment: Did the _Future Reserved Words_ change? In the linked PDF I don’t see `int` or `bool` etc. in the listing.

Comment: I cannot see `let` in here, but I see it in the docu: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Answer (score 20):

I was just reading about this in **[JavaScript & jQuery: The Missing Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449399029)**:

> *Not all of these reserved words will cause problems in all browsers, but it’s best to steer clear of these names when naming variables.*
>
> **JavaScript keywords:** `break, case, catch, continue, debugger, default, delete, do, else, false, finally, for, function, if, in, instanceof, new, null, return, switch, this, throw, true, try, typeof, var, void, while, with`.
>
> **Reserved for future use:** `abstract, boolean, byte, char, class, const, double, enum, export, extends, final, float, goto, implements, import, int, interface, let, long, native, package, private, protected, public, short, static, super, synchronized, throws, transient, volatile, yield`.
>
> **Pre-defined global variables in the browser:** `alert, blur, closed, document, focus, frames, history, innerHeight, innerWidth, length, location, navigator, open, outerHeight, outerWidth, parent, screen, screenX, screenY, statusbar, window`.

Comment: Used location in a script and got very odd behaviour, very useful post.

Comment: "Reserved for future use" :: All Java words... quite lazy really.

Comment: Note that “reserved” is not the same as “pre-initialized”. In the browser, `alert` is already initialized, but nothing stops you from reassigning `alert = 5`. However, you cannot set `window` to 5, but you can use it as a local variable. That's not possible with reserved keywords, future use, `null`, `false`, `true`.

Comment: The more voted answers missed `yield` by my quick check so +1 from me. These can in ES5.1 be activated by strict mode: `implements`     `interface`   `let`       `package`    `private`
`protected`      `public`      `static`    `yield`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a browser and language version agnostic way to determine if a particular string is treated as a keyword by the JavaScript engine. Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16157652/1083663) which provides the core of the solution.

```
function isReservedKeyword(wordToCheck) {
    var reservedWord = false;
    if (/^[a-z]+$/.test(wordToCheck)) {
        try {
            eval('var ' + wordToCheck + ' = 1');
        } catch (error) {
            reservedWord = true;
        }
    }
    return reservedWord;
}
```

Comment: If you have to use `eval` for anything, it most likely means you're doing it wrong.

Comment: This is perfect for a test case run at build time, completely valid as long as it's not something you have exposed at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

None of the current answers warn that regardless of ES-Dialect, browsers tend to have their own lists of reserved keywords, methods etc on top of what ES dictates.

For example, IE9 prohibits use of logical names like: `addFilter`, `removeFilter` (they, among others, are reserved methods).

See http://www.jabcreations.com/blog/internet-explorer-9 for a more extensive 'currently known' list specific to IE9. I have yet find any official reference to them on msdn (or elsewhere).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list from Eloquent JavaScript book:

- `break`
- `case`
- `catch`
- `class`
- `const`
- `continue`
- `debugger`
- `default`
- `delete`
- `do`
- `else`
- `enum`
- `export`
- `extend`
- `false`
- `finally`
- `for`
- `function`
- `if`
- `implements`
- `import`
- `in`
- `instanceof`
- `interface`
- `let`
- `new`
- `null`
- `package`
- `private`
- `protected`
- `public`
- `return`
- `static`
- `super`
- `switch`
- `this`
- `throw`
- `true`
- `try`
- `typeof`
- `var`
- `void`
- `while`
- `with`
- `yield`

Answer (score 0):

benc's answer is excellent, but for my two cents, I like the w3schools' page on this:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

In addition to listing the keywords reserved by the standard, it also has a long list of keywords you *should* avoid in certain contexts; for example, not using the name `alert` when writing code to be run in a browser. It helped me figure out why certain words were highlighting as keywords in my editor even though I knew they weren't keywords.