# JavaScript warning on var element

Tags: javascript, string, exception, warnings, identifier

Have defined:

```
var ru_cryptopro_npcades_10_native_bridge = {

    callbacksCount : 1,
    callbacks : {},

    resultForCallback : function resultForCallback(callbackId, resultArray) {

        var callback = ru_cryptopro_npcades_10_native_bridge.callbacks[callbackId];

        if (!callback) return;

        callback.apply(null, resultArray);

    },

    call : function call(functionName, args, callback) {

        var hasCallback = callback && typeof callback == "function";
        var callbackId = hasCallback ? ru_cryptopro_npcades_10_native_bridge.callbacksCount++ : 0;

        if (hasCallback) ru_cryptopro_npcades_10_native_bridge.callbacks[callbackId] = callback;

        var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        var arrObjs = new Array("_CPNP_handle");

        try {

            iframe.setAttribute("src", "cpnp-js-call:" + functionName + ":" + callbackId+ ":" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(args, arrObjs)));

        }
        catch(e) {

            alert(e);

        }

        document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
        iframe = null;

    },

};
```

Have got such warning:
***Warning  1   Expected identifier or string   C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WebAppSelf3\WebAppSelf3\js\CadesLoad.js    453 1   WebAppSelf3***

Why?

Comment: What's line 453 of `CadesLoad.js`? (I think that's where that error means to look...)

Comment: @AlexWayne it's a last line of the provided code here

Comment: @AlexWayne proof: http://s24.postimage.org/i6tsa511h/Screenshot_274.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome parses that just fine, but I have a hunch whatever environment you have that is throwing this error doesn't like that trailing comma in your object literal.

```
    },

};
```

Which may need to be:

```
    }

};
```

Which again, is wierd, because this seem to work in at least some browsers:
http://jsfiddle.net/Aa6yc/1/

Though it's definately not good form.

Comment: IE will choke on this badly and complain like no tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

The error is referring to your hanging `,` comma after the big `call: function .....{}` block. It's malformed object.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this types of errors can often be a misplaced comma in a object or array definition:

```
var obj = {
   id: 23,
   name: "test",  <--
}
```

Reference: [Possible cases for Javascript error: "Expected identifier, string or number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149762/possible-cases-for-javascript-error-expected-identifier-string-or-number)