# tzCheckbox expected identifier, string or number

Tags: javascript, jquery

i just tzCheckbox as fancy ON/OFF and under IE8 i have error in this line

```
// Creating the new checkbox markup:
var checkBox = $('<span>', {
    class: 'tzCheckBox ' + (this.checked ? 'checked' : ''),
    html: '<span class="tzCBContent">' + labels[this.checked ? 0 : 1] +
          '</span><span class="tzCBPart"></span>'
});
```

and error says: expected identifier, string or number.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem under ie8 but, now I solved.
You need to change class part like below.

```
'class' : 'tzCheckBox'+(this.checked?' checked':''),
```

refer this 
[Possible cases for Javascript error: "Expected identifier, string or number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149762/possible-cases-for-javascript-error-expected-identifier-string-or-number)
One of these answers was helpful.