# Adding methods to prototype objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm making my way through [Murach’s JavaScript and jQuery (3rd Edition)](https://www.murach.com/shop-books/web-development-books/murach-s-javascript-and-jquery-3rd-edition-detail) and I've encountered a compiler error with code from the book. I've triple checked my syntax against the book's syntax and I think I can rule it out. I also looked at the [errata page](https://www.murach.com/images/downloads/javascript_and_jquery_3rd_Ed/jqu3Correx.pdf) and I don't find a reference to the page I'm on.

I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149762/possible-cases-for-javascript-error-expected-identifier-string-or-number/2149815), but I didn't find anything applicable to my issue.

Here is my object constructor:

```
var Invoice = function(subtotal, taxRate) {
    this.subtotal = subtotal;
    this.taxRate = taxRate;
};
```

I run into trouble when attempting to add methods to the prototype object:

```
// The getTaxAmount method is added to the Invoice prototype
Invoice.prototype.getTaxAmount: function() {
// Compiler whines right here ^ and     ^
    return (subtotal * this.taxRate);
};

// The getInvoiceTotal method is added to the Invoice prototype
Invoice.prototype.getInvoiceTotal: function() {
// Compiler whines right here ^ and     ^
    return subtotal + this.getTaxAmount(this.subtotal);
};
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code with Debugger for Chrome. The prompt in VS Code says it wants a `;` at the first spot it complains and `[js] identifier expected` at the second spot it complains.

Thank you for reading. I welcome your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is either

```
Invoice.prototype.getInvoiceTotal = function() {}
```

This is because `prototype` itself is an object.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for the quick assist on this. That's the first error I've found in the book after getting ~500 pages deep :) I'll accept when the timer goes off.

Comment: @Adrian `subtotal` should be `this.subtotal` too, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a syntax error. You rather use an assignment operator, `=`, for such work:

```
// The getTaxAmount method is added to the Invoice prototype
Invoice.prototype.getTaxAmount = function() {
    return (subtotal * this.taxRate);
};

// The getInvoiceTotal method is added to the Invoice prototype
Invoice.prototype.getInvoiceTotal = function() {
    return subtotal + this.getTaxAmount(this.subtotal);
};
```

In addition to that, you could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to assign properties to an object, like this:

```
Object.assign(Invoice.prototype, {
    getTaxAmount: function() {
        return (subtotal * this.taxRate);
    },
    getInvoiceTotal: function() {
        return subtotal + this.getTaxAmount(this.subtotal);
    }
});
```

Notice that you don't use a semicolon at the end of the function when using the latter.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. Jorg beat you by a few mins.

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp), the correct way to add a function to a prototype would be as follows:

`Invoice.prototype.getInvoiceTotal = function(){ **your fx here** };`

From the look of things, you are using a `:` instead of a `=`, this may be what is causing you grief.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an equal sign. Colon is for variable values for JSON.

```
Invoice.prototype.getInvoiceTotal = function() {
// Compiler whines right here ^ and     ^
    return subtotal + this.getTaxAmount(this.subtotal);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> All JavaScript objects inherit properties and methods from a prototype.
>
> The JavaScript prototype property also allows you to add new methods objects constructors:

ie : Date objects inherit from Date.prototype. Array objects inherit from Array.prototype. Person objects inherit from Person.prototype.

```
<script>
  var Invoice = function(subtotal, taxRate) {
  this.subtotal = subtotal;
  this.taxRate = taxRate;
};

Invoice.prototype.getTaxAmount = function() {
    return (subtotal * this.taxRate);
};

var myTax= new Invoice(10,5);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"My tax amount is " + myTax.getTaxAmount (); 
</script>
```