# SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number edge

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

my website works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not on edge.

The website is not loading correctly and i got this message :

> SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
>   index.js (6199,13)

This refers to config.js:

```
const appName = 'mywebsite';
const databaseName = 'databaseName';
const serverPort = process.env.PORT || 3122;


const apiUrl = "/";

const source=require("./client_id.json")

const completeConfig = {

    default: {

        appName,
        serverPort,
        apiUrl,
        databaseUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URI || `mongodb://localhost/${databaseName}`,
        jsonOptions: {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
    },

    development: {
        appUrl: `http://localhost:${serverPort}`
    },

    production: {
    appUrl: `http://localhost:${serverPort}`
    }

}

const mailConfig = {
  user: "user@user.fr",
  clientId: source.web.client_id,
  clientSecret: source.web.client_secret,
  refreshToken: 'refreshToken',
  accessToken: 'accessToken'
}


module.exports = {
    config: { ...completeConfig.default, ...completeConfig[process.env.NODE_ENV] },
    completeConfig,
    mailConfig,
}
```

specially this parts :

```
module.exports = {
    config: { ...completeConfig.default, ...completeConfig[process.env.NODE_ENV] },
    completeConfig,
    mailConfig,
}
```

Here is the debog console from edge :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW4fD.png)

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Which version of edge are you using? It seems the spread operator is not supported in the one you're using. https://caniuse.com/#search=spread%20operator

Comment: @rlecaro2 You right my version of edge is deprecated to use spread operator ! i update edge and now it's working thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The misplaced comma at the end of your module.exports object could be the reason of this strange behavior.

Try with the following code:

```
module.exports = {
    config: { ...completeConfig.default, ...completeConfig[process.env.NODE_ENV] },
    completeConfig,
    mailConfig // Just removing the comma here
}
```

For more information about this error, see [Possible cases for Javascript error: "Expected identifier, string or number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149762/possible-cases-for-javascript-error-expected-identifier-string-or-number)