# What is the `name` keyword in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, keyword

When I typed this apparently innocent snippet of code:

```
values.name
```

gedit highlighted **name** as a keyword.  However, **name** is not listed by the pages linked to by [an answer to a question about reserved keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255/reserved-keywords-in-javascript#60396).  I also did a couple trivial tests in SpiderMonkey, but **name** seemed to act like an ordinary identifier.

A Google search didn't tell me much either.  However, I did find [a page listing **name** in "Other JavaScript Keywords".](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm)  My guess is that **name** is a function or a member of some DOM element and does not intrude on the namespace.

Is **name** really a keyword in JavaScript?  If so, what does it do?

Comment: `name` is (was) used as an attribute of the `a` element, so it could occur in DOM code. Maybe this is the reason your editor is highlighting it.

Comment: Actually gedit highlights `name` as a property. But in the classic color scheme properties and keywords are using the same style definition. Because the parsing capabilities of gedit are quite limited though only a small set of important property names get highlighted with this style, for example regexp properties like `global`, `source`, `lastIndex` and function properties like `prototype`, `length` and `name`.

Comment: In chrome,  name is behaving strangely like global object from localhost. i.e Within a function var name ='...' is modifying original window.name and therefore 'name; is available outside the fn scope. However when I run it separately in console and Plunkr its showing undefined/or Original window Object. In IE its behaving normal(i.e undefined/empty in localhost)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Its not a javascript reserved word, its an html attribute. Any DOM element can have a name. Looks like your syntax editor will still highlight it.

Comment: It is not a `reserved word` but it is one of `JavaScript built-in objects, properties, and methods`: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Answer (score 8):

(I know this was asked 2 years ago but, ...)
This happened to me also, for example this below would not work.

```
name = document.getElementById('nombre');
//something else
name.className = 'thinking';
```

Instead I changed it to

```
username = document.getElementById('nombre');
//something else
username.className = 'thinking';
```

and it did work!
Yeah, alright that's all, but it's something I find maybe quite interesting, also because of the 'name' attribute of the 'a' tag. Something to watch out for.

Comment: The question isn't really about problems with reusing the global `name` variable. In contrast to using a plain `name` in global scope the usage of `values.name` *does* work, it's just displayed abnormally in the text editor.

Comment: `window.name` has a setter which stringifies the value before storing it. Just declare it with `var` in a non-global scope.

Answer (score 6):

**What?** 
'name' is the property of the window object of the browser. It is a built-in property in JavaScript. 
Visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

**Why @deprecated** 
window.name is still in use in JavaScript, but it is planned to be removed in the future. 
Visit: [The Difference Between Deprecated, Depreciated and Obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208091/the-difference-between-deprecated-depreciated-and-obsolete)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a reserved word it's a variable (it is window.name) I'm not sure what it's defined by though.

Comment: The mentioned text editor does not highlight `name` though. It only highlights it when it's used as a property name like in `window.name`. Then only the `.name` part gets highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also, for example, the following didn't work for me while I was testing the call, bind functions.

```
var name={
firstname: 'Abhishek',
lastname: 'Agarwal',

fullname: function{
    var fname = this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
    return fname;
}

function printname(){
    console.log(this.fullname());
}
var final=printname.bind(name);
final();
```

This didn't actually perform the task and instead when I replaced "name" occurences by "myname" or literally anything else, it did work!

Comment: Interesting, what browser were you using?  Your code snippet has some syntax errors, like missing end brace for var name, and `function` not followed by parens.  [I cleaned up the syntax and got it to work with name](https://tio.run/##RY7LEoIwDEX3/YrsaAdl7ciw8FMC8qjW1GkLLhy@vfYBmGwy9@bm5IEL2s7ItzsvF@8XNED46qGBL4NQgzTWReUKxa2dpJ36Z3FKlsK/M6L5oApGDs1KZWeYqXNSExfbvVgRMmwUF05WBwRKKEKXWd4B9ZE0vZsN5XBWV7bWjO0YeBtJKcNF5nWarFZ9pfTIM2v7jQtRs5Wx9IwkVM2RrVpJdx6nsJI8Hgbvfw).

Answer (score 0):

strangely for me too, below code did not work for me when I am learning about call, apply and bind in javascript. I was breaking my head for half an hour till I figured out I am not doing any logical mistake but in the variable name lies the problem.

> var name = {firstName: 'sarwan',lastName :'kumar'};
>
> function say(){  console.log('' + this.firstName + ' ' +  this.lastName); }
>
> say.call(name);

This gives me the result as

> "undefined undefined"

And I was like literally breaking my head suspecting somehow this is not passed to say function, tried changing other parts of code except the name variable, still did not work for me. But later figured out somehow, at the expense of spoiling my mood for good half an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Visual Studio code editor while having enabled Eslint,you can see that 'name' is classified as '@deprecated'. Although from Google it is not clear whether 'name' is a reserved keyword or not, the '@deprecated' label hints that the feature in question however is correct maybe as an effort to support backward compatibility ... etc, currently the feature has been disapproved of and one is encouraged to avoid.