# Able to assign any value to "name" but not able to assign document.getElementById('name') to it why?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign document.getElementById('name') to 'name' but it is not getting assigned why ?

```
<body>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var name;
    console.log('before change name = ',  name);// [object HTMLInputElement]
    name = 'change value of name';
    console.log('after change name = ', name);//change value of name. name is changeable here
    name = 5;
    console.log('again change name = ', name);// 5. name is changeable here 
    var worker = new Worker('/js/worker.js');
    name = document.getElementById('name');//name is not changeable here why ?
    console.log('assign input name value name = ', name);//[object HTMLInputElement]
    name.onkeyup = function(){
      worker.postMessage({msg:'send to worker'});
    };
    worker.onmessage = function(e){
      console.log(e.data, 'from worker');
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

I just want to get access of `document.getElementById('name')` into `name` but This line `name = document.getElementById('name')` has not effect on `name` why ?

Comment: Edited my answer to fit your clarified intentions.

Comment: Not working yet. This line `name = document.getElementById('name');` has no effect on `name`.
If I do change `name` to `nam` or anything rather than `name` then its working fine

Comment: Even the comment in your source code says that after assigning the line you question `name` contains `"[object HTMLInputElement]"`. So what exactly is your question? http://jsbin.com/hidocobixa/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: It should hold the reference of document.getElementById('name');. But it is not

Comment: You are wrong. It does. Check the JSBin I linked. What exactly makes you think it does not hold a reference?

Comment: Its really a strange behaviour. when i running this code on browser I am getting this "before change name =  [object HTMLInputElement]
(index):8 after change name =  change value of name
(index):10 again change name =  5
(index):13 Reference of input =  [object HTMLInputElement]"................
But when I am running it in jsfiddle then the result is ok

Comment: @Connexo please check it on browser

Comment: What do you mean by "check it on browser"?

Comment: @connexo make a file of the code and type the url of that file in browser and then run that file and check the console output

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the DOM element with the `id="name"` to `name`. Probably what you want is the DOM element's current value.

```
name = document.getElementById('name').value;
```

#### Edit:

Since what you need is to **attach an event handler** to the element, you need to use `addEventListener()` method:

```
name = document.getElementById('name');
name.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    worker.postMessage({msg:"'send to worker'});
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: document.getElementById('name').value  should be used

Comment: I want to get access of  document.getElementById('name') into name so that i can add event on it

Comment: Not working yet.
This line `name = document.getElementById('name');` has no effect on `name`

Comment: Of course that line does have exactly the expected effect. Afterwards, the variable `name` holds a reference to the DOM element http://jsbin.com/hidocobixa/edit?html,js,console,output.

Comment: @connexo are you looking into issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well this all depends on what you are tring to assign. Your question is not very clear.

If you are trying to set the value of 'name' (the element) to the value of 'name' (the javascript variable), you would use:

```
document.getElementById("name").value = name;
```

If you are trying to set the value of 'name' (the variable) to the value of 'name' (the element), you would use:

```
name = document.getElementById("name").value; //(As shown in the previous answer)
```

If you are trying to display the value of 'name' (the variable) in the innerHTML of a (p, li, td, etc.) you would use:

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
```

Comment: I am just getting access of document.getElementById('name') to name varialbe so that i can add event on it later
 name.onkeyup = function(){
      worker.postMessage({msg:'send to worker'});
    };

Answer (score 0):

It seems the reason we are not able to use 'name' as a global variable is the fact that 'name' is the property of the window object of the browser. It is a built-in property in JavaScript.
Visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

It was answered here: [What is the `name` keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663740/what-is-the-name-keyword-in-javascript/2663762)