# React router v4 Link to

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, router

This is an invalid syntax for some reason

```
 <Link to={'/page/with/' + id + '/' + name}>Some param Page</Link>
```

The entire error is this and the app just doesn't compiles

```
Line 17:  Unexpected use of 'name'  no-restricted-globals

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

But this one is valid

```
<Link to={'/page/with/' + id}>Some param Page</Link>
```

So my question is how can i make a link that matches

```
 <Route path="/page/with/:id/:name" component={SomeParamPage}/>
```

The route is valid if write directly in the url it works, the problem is the `Link`

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

let id = 2;
let name = 'sasho';
const Header = () => (
    <h2>
        Header
        <br/>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <br/>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        <br/>
        <Link to="/about-us">About us</Link>
        <br/>
        <Link to="/contact">Home</Link>
        <br/>
        <Link to={'/page/with/' + id + '/' + name}>Some param Page</Link>
    </h2>
);

export default Header;
```

Comment: This error is related to [this page](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals)

Comment: Can you show the code where `name` is declared and assigned a value? Sounds like an issue with how it gets created.

Comment: ok i eddeited my main post

Comment: Can you try `to={\`/page/with/${id}/${name}\`}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error here

```
Line 17:  Unexpected use of 'name'  no-restricted-globals

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

`name` is a keyword in JS, so it throws an error. It's like trying to name a variable `this` - you're going to run into issues. Try picking a different variable name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663740/what-is-the-name-keyword-in-javascript according to this it's not, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Ah, thanks for the edit! You are creating `name` outside of `Header` scope. let and const are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. To fix this, just move `name` into the `Header` stateless component:

```
const Header = () => {
  let name = 'sasho';
  let id = 2;
  return (
        <h2>
          Header
          <br/>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <br/>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          <br/>
          <Link to="/about-us">About us</Link>
          <br/>
          <Link to="/contact">Home</Link>
          <br/>
          <Link to={'/page/with/' + id + '/' + name}>Some param Page</Link>
        </h2>
    );
}
```