# Defining array in javascript and keeping the name of array as name

Tags: javascript, arrays

While executing the below code in javascript:

```
var name=["Pankaj","Kumar"] ;

    for( var i=0;i<name.length;i++)
    {
        console.log("Hello "+name[i]);
    }
```

According to me ,it should output :

```
Hello Pankaj   
Hello Kumar
```

But javascript engine outputs :

```
Hello P  
Hello a  
Hello n  
Hello k  
Hello a  
Hello j  
Hello ,  
Hello K  
Hello u  
Hello m  
Hello a  
Hello r
```

If we change the name of array as **names** ,then it outputs according to expectations:

```
Hello Pankaj  
Hello Kumar
```

name is not a javascript reserved keyword .

Could you please let me know the reason for this behavior.

Comment: `name` definitely exist in the global scope.

Comment: `name` is not a reserved word, but it is a global: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question has it all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663740/what-is-the-name-keyword-in-javascript)

Name is already attached to the window you're in as `window.name` so avoid using it or use `IIFE` as below to avoid polluting global namespace

```js
(function(){
  var name=["Pankaj","Kumar"] ;

    for( var i=0;i<name.length;i++)
    {
        console.log("Hello "+name[i]);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Your explanation is wrong. `window.name` has nothing to do with html attributes

Comment: the IIFE is a more creative answer than "change the variable names."

Comment: @M.Davis No, `window.name` is about the browsing context (i.e. the browser window/tab) and has nothing to do with HTML. Of course, the IIFE is the correct solution.

Comment: @Bergi my bad, I was looking at the wrong link