# Using name as an array variable in table in javascript

Tags: javascript, console

I am new to javascript basics and am learning it now.

So I would like to know why the following code has an additional ***'Value'*** column for ***'name'*** variable instead of considering it as a normal variable and assigning each string to an index.

```
var name=['Jane','Beulah','Jai'];
var age=[21,21,20];
var city=['BLR','COI','CHN'];
console.table([name,age,city]);
```

Actual Output:

[image]

I seem to get the correct output if I change the variable from ***'name'*** to someother different name.
Is it because name is a keyword for console.table()? or is it because of some other reason?

Comment: `name` in this scope refers to `window.name`, which is a string property. That is why it implicitly adds a `toString()` which results in `"Jane,Beulah,Jai"`. You should rename it or change its scrope. Yet better rename it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the \`name\` keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663740/what-is-the-name-keyword-in-javascript) Your case is in the answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

As @Lain said in the comment, `name` gets confused with the global `window.name`.

Changing to `names` will solve the issue: (console.table only prints in browser console, not in stackoverflow console)

```js
var names=['Jane','Beulah','Jai'];
var age=[21,21,20];
var city=['BLR','COI','CHN'];
console.table([names,age,city]);
```