# Why is the name variable displayed with a strikethrough on VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Here is my Javascript code on VS Code:

[image: const name]
[image: var name]

In the `console.log(name variable);` the `name` variable is displayed with a strikethrough symbol on VS Code. But the result showing on my browser is right (no error).

Also, the tooltip shown on VS Code is "`const name : void`".

The same thing is happening if I use

```
document.getElementById('demo10').innerHTML = name;
```

or

```
document.write(name);
```

```
var name = 'Smith';
document.getElementById('demo10').innerHTML = name;
console.log(name);
```

Comment: try to make `name` `const`

Comment: try `const name = 'Smith'`

Comment: Most likely linting warning. Its complaining that since you are not changing the value of name after the declaration, you can make it **const**ant.

Comment: @DeC same thing happing when i use const name = 'Smith';

Comment: @GowthamRajJ same thing happening when i used const name = 'Smith';

Comment: What does happen if you hold the cursor on the name?

Comment: @iwaduarte tooltip showing : const name : void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer:

`name` is an obsolete property of the [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object. When you see a strikethrough on a variable, VS Code knows that it is deprecated.

Long Answer:

[What is the `name` keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66564658/13829657)

Answer (score 3):

It is a deprecated variable. This is particularly annoying on loops when we are just using the index of an array, or a foreach(). To stop this behavior add this to your user settings JSON file. This may help someone out in the future.

```
// Controls strikethrough deprecated variables.
"editor.showDeprecated": false,
```

In the most recent versions there is also a checkbox in the UI settings under "editor".

Answer (score -1):

Better update the version of vs code in the new one there is more shortcuts and no annoying errors.
thanks

Comment: I am running on the latest version and still have the error.