# Multi line chart D3.js Json data structure

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to modify [this](https://jsfiddle.net/caravinden/vcuzxhdb/) fiddle

where in instead of this Json

```
var data = [{"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Day1","price":40},{"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Day2","price":23.18},{"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Day3","price":24.43}
```

data I want to pass this Json format `{
                "day1": 10,
                "day2": 154,
                "day3": 24,
                "day4": 48,
                "day5": 154,
                "day6": 48,
                "day7": 154,
                "day8": 154,
                "lineName": "cars",
            }.
            {
                "day1": 10,
                "day2": 154,
                "day3": 24,
                "day4": 48,
                "day5": 154,
                "day6": 48,
                "day7": 154,
                "day8": 154,
                "lineName": "bikes",
            },
            {
                "day1": 10,
                "day2": 154,
                "day3": 24,
                "day4": 48,
                "day5": 154,
                "day6": 48,
                "day7": 154,
                "day8": 154,
                "lineName": "planes",
            }`

I am new to JS and D3.js can any one give me some hint or example on hoe can i modify the code that it would accept the above Json . or any way of massaging the data

Answer (score 1):

Timescale is not suitable for the domain

- [Use Ordinal scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Ordinal-Scales.md)

`var domain = ["Day 1","Day 2", "Day 3","Day 4","Day 5","Day 6","Day 7"];
   var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
       .domain(domain)
       .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(xScale)
       .tickSize(0)
       .orient("bottom");
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);`

Comment: this is my codepen goo.gl/1jrooW  can u help me how should i remove the existing axis

Comment: @Rakesh May i know the use of date filed in JSON data as well as the xAxisArray variable?

Comment: i have edited the Q pls have a look on the top ...i am trying to convert http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/88d2a87b72ea894c285c line graph

Comment: @Rakesh This is an axis oriented graph(x/y). X axis will be date and y axis will be price. Then what is the point in converting date field(mmm-yyyy) to day1..etc. Possibly you can do axis text formatting its a better option. I don't get the mapping of day1.day2...to date field really?

Comment: thats just an example i just want to create a multiline graph with x axis as Days and Y axis as numeric data can you provide a simple example for the same and also i have edited the Q what i exactly want to acheive.

Comment: do u have a sample json to share?

Comment: {
    "day1": 10,
    "day2": 154,
    "day3": 24,
    "day4": 48,
    "day5": 154,
    "day6": 48,
    "day7": 154,
    "lineName": "cars",
   }.
   {
    "day1": 10,
    "day2": 154,
    "day3": 24,
    "day4": 48,
    "day5": 154,
    "day6": 48,
    "day7": 154,
    "lineName": "bikes",
   },
   {
    "day1": 10,
    "day2": 154,
    "day3": 24,
    "day4": 48,
    "day5": 154,
    "day6": 48,
    "day7": 154,
    "lineName": "planes",
   }
the lineName will decide the color of the line i.e wheteher it is a plane or bike or car

Comment: yes....Thanks a lot....i have also posted the image of  the line chart which i want to  implement ...can  u pls provide any help...or some examples on the same....with the exact UI as that of example

Comment: my major problem is in the JSON data structure as the one used in your example is different and the on which i have is different...can u provide any help on that ....sorry if it sounds silly....i am not so good at js...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of time scale

```
var x = d3.time.scale().domain(Array).range([0, width]);
```

Use ordinal scale

```
var ar = ["Day 1","Day 2", "Day 3","Day 4","Day 5","Day 6","Day 7"];
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(arr)
    .rangeBands([0, width]);
```

Comment: Array is a keyword so above code won't work it seems

Comment: yeah true i just copied it in a jiffy :P corrected it.

Comment: @Aravind What's a "keyword"?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado its a reserved word  variable name should not be Array..

Comment: @GerardoFurtado http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp. Avoid  reserved words in naming conventions

Comment: I know that, it was just a rhetorical question. "Array" is *not* a reserved word: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896744/why-javascript-doesnt-include-reserved-keywords-such-as-object-array-fun