# Is it possible to get a list of reserved words(variables, functions, object names) in JS?

Tags: javascript

There is a lot of great information [on this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255/reserved-keywords-in-javascript)

I can grab the keywords from websites provided there, **BUT** I am asking is it possible to grab reserved keywords in real time ? Maybe there is some structure where they are stored?

For global objects in window, I can grab them with this:

```
for(var i in window) doSomethingWith(i)
```

But I also need all the language specific keywords like: **if, case, switch,** etc.

**SORRY** I didn't want to write "then". I was coding in **Pascal** in the last hour(remembering old times) and god damn it stuck into my head!

**What I want to do:** It may sound strange, however I am building an app where you can create elements, they have names, values, formulas and formulas are pure JS formulas, except I run a regular expression to modify variables a bit and want to leave the javascript syntax.

For example if formula is: `if (a < b) { c = d; }`
In this case I would like to modify only **a, b, c** and **d**.

If formula would be something like: `switch(a) { case 0: a=b; break; case 1: b=c; ... }`
In this case I would like to filter out "**switch, break, case**".

Well maybe I should delete this question

Comment: Why would you need them in real time? its not like they change that often. just pull them off a wbsite and put them in an array constant in your code if you need "Real time"

Comment: @Limey, just asking if there's a solution instead of grabbing :)

Comment: What do you mean by "grabbing"?

Comment: Consult the specification: http://es5.github.com/#x7.6.1.1

Comment: @lukas.pukenis - Thanks for clearing that up by offering another generic, undefined term. Being specific is a great way to make it easier for people to help you!

Comment: @jahroy, Thank you! Please read the updated answer

Comment: I don't see any reason to delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on the tubes (you should always google first) came up with this bit of code I would never expect to see, a reserved word checker.  I didn't even try playing with it, so don't know if its right or not.

```
https://github.com/revolution42/Javascript-Reserved-Word-Checker/blob/master/checker.js
```

Comment: +1 I always google first, just couldn't think of a simple solution. Thanks for a great link

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you google "javascript reserved words" you get this:

```
abstract (*)
as (2)
boolean
break
byte
case
catch
char
class (2)
continue
const (2)
debugger (*)
default
delete
do
double
else
enum (*)
export (2)
extends (2)
false
final
finally
float
for
function
goto (*)
if
implements (*)
import (2)
in
instanceof
int
interface (2)
is (2)
long
namespace (2)
native (*)
new
null
package (2)
private (2)
protected (*)
public (2)
return
short
static (2)
super (2)
switch
synchronized (*)
this
throw
throws (*)
transient (*)
true
try
typeof
use (2)
var
void
volatile (*)
while
with
```

Source:  http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm

I'm not sure what you mean by "grab" them, but you could put all those words in an array and search for each element of the array in a block of text...

Comment: That's perfect, however there's no keyword like "then" in here. I would like to have them all

Comment: @lukas.pukenis - I didn't know "then" was a keyword.  According to that reference (which is supposed to include keywords that haven't even been implemented yet), it is not a keyword.

Comment: well, yes, not a keyword, however a reserved word

Comment: @lukas.pukenis - Not sure why it is "reserved" in your opinion.  If you have some words that you want to reserve for your own reasons, you could add them to the array.  Here's an even better reference with more "special" words.  It does NOT include "then" either.