# Calling saving method whenever I call save method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class like this:

```
class X extends Y {
  public save() {

  }
}

abstract class Y {
  public saving() {

  }
}

const x = new X;
x.save();
```

How can I make sure each call to `save` triggers `saving` before?

In PHP, we can use `__call` and check the method name. Is there any similar approach with Javascript?

Comment: Is that a JavaScript code? `abstract` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255/reserved-keywords-in-javascript).

Comment: @RBT Typescript

Answer (score 1):

First of all define you abstract class Y before extending it. An then you can use `super` keyword to access base class members. See the code below.

```js
abstract class Y {
  public saving() {
    console.log("Y Class Saving")
  }
}
class X extends Y {
  public save() {
    super.saving();
    console.log("X Class Save")
  }
}
const x = new X();
x.save();
```

Can test the above code here on [**Playground**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Base%20%7B%0A%09constructor%28%29%7B%0A%09%09setTimeout%28%28%29=%3E%7B%0A%09%09%09this.initialized%28%29;%0A%09%09%7D,%201000%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09initialized%28%29%7B%0A%09%09console.log%28%22Base%20initialized%22%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Derived%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0A%09initialized%28%29%7B%0A%09%09console.log%28%22Derived%20initialized%22%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20test:Derived%20=%20new%20Derived%28%29;)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: What I want is a way to hook classes during runtime and giving them ability to call methods without defining them explicitly. We can do that in PHP by relying on __call, for example. So, I'm not going to do this.saving() in the save method, but rather teach my class to call saving whenever I call save. This is a good answer but I already know about it.

Comment: in PHP `If a class implements __call(), then if an object of that class is called with a method that doesn't exist __call() is called instead`. Is that what you want if the `Save()` method is not defined it should call `Saving()` method of base class??

Comment: We use magic methods such as call in PHP to call more methods. Laravel framework for example, calls `saving` method when you call `save`. What I want is something similar. For example, if I can listen for calling methods in JS, I can simply do something like `this.saving.apply(...args)` or something like this.