# How it's possible to declare a variable named let in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variable-declaration

I'm wondering how a variable can be named `let` because `let` is a reserved word in JavaScript!

```
var let = "a value"; // this works!!!
let let = "a value"; // luckily this doesn't work
```

While reading about reserved words in JavaScript I used [this website](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) and also I checked [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255/reserved-keywords-in-javascript) (see the answer of **art4theSould**) and both of them (also the same thing in other sources) said that `let` -as everyone can image- is a reserved word in JavaScript.

Comment: it's clear you cannot, you may try to add a symbole or a special character

Comment: Try putting `"use strict";` before that first declaration.

Comment: Reserved words only applies to identifiers, as opposed to object property names.  `var let` adds a property `let` to the `window` object.  This makes sense, because object properties with reserved names can be accessed using the array syntax.  Whereas `let let` wants to create an identifier in the local scope using a reserved word, which is illegal.

Comment: @Pointy Yes by adding strict mode I got the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word`

Comment: @Amy If the `var let` declaration is inside a function, it doesn't add a property to the `window` object, but it still works.

Comment: Per [the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) in the accepted answer to the SO question you posted, some reserved words only apply in strict mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords, `let` is only reserved when it's found in strict mode code.

This appears to be for backward compatibility, so that pre-ES6 code is not impacted. This explains why `let let` is not allowed: since you're actually using the new `let` keyword, pre-ES6 compatibility is obviously not a concern.