# Why enum is a reserved keyword in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, keyword

I was trying to declare a variable named `enum` but got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word` error.

I'm not using typescript, so why is `enum` a reserved keyword?

I was [searching for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255/reserved-keywords-in-javascript/12114140) and realized that `enum` is a reserved keyword, but `protected` is also reserved and doesn't give me the error.

[image]

I also couldn't find what `enum` is used for or how it works in vanilla js.

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords and the text says: *"The following are reserved as future keywords by the ECMAScript specification. They have no special functionality at present, but they might at some future time, so they cannot be used as identifiers."*

Comment: Why not? It's used in many languages, so ECMAScript reserved it for future possible use, so that people don't start using it all over their code, making it impossible for them to use it later.

Comment: `protected` is only reserved in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, now it makes sense. That is what I needed

Comment: Note that since Javascript is very case-sensitive, you could still use `Enum` as it is not reserved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords)

> The following are reserved as future keywords by the ECMAScript specification. They have no special functionality at present, but they might at some future time, so they cannot be used as identifiers.

And `enum` is always reserved keyword.

Comment: beat me to it !  just found that.  Cheers.